# How to get redirect url?

Tags: python, urllib2

I am using urllib.request to perform a sequence of http calls in python 3.6. I need to retrieve the value of a 302 http redirect that is returned in response to a urllib.request.urlopen call like so...

```
import urllib.request

... many previous http calls ...

post_data = {'foo': 'bar', 'some': 'otherdata'}
encoded = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_data).encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request('https://some-url', encoded)
redirected_url = urllib.request.urlopen(req).geturl()
```

I get an error like...

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: Found - Redirection to url 'gibberish://login_callback?code=ABCD......' is not allowed
```

What I need is to actually get the url that is being returned in the 302 as the .geturl() method should provide, but instead I get an error.

Please no answers like "Hey use this other library that I'm super into right now" as we've spent a long time building this script using urllib2 and we have very little python knowledge.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html) could help?

Comment: Check out the requests module if you haven't, might make your life a bit easier.

Comment: *Please no answers like "Hey use this other library that I'm super into right now" as we've spent a long time building this script using urllib2 and we have very little python knowledge* - generally to be fair, `requests` removes all the boiler plate code you've probably been writing re: encoding, redirects, secure connections, handling parameters or json data etc... You might want to evaluate changing now if you haven't gotten too far down the rabbit hole.

Comment: (for instance - your above code would be: `r = requests.post('https://some-url', data=post_data)` to make the request... then `redirected_url = r.url` to get the final url you ended up on (there's even `r.history` which will be a list of all redirects (in case you got bounced around))

Comment: @JonClements appreciate the advice.  We might have to go down that route just explaining to mgmt we spent a week on it and now are starting over is not appealing.

Comment: So tried to plug in the Requests library for just that call.  Get the same error, basically it crashes when it gets a 302 pointing to a url that looks like 'gibberish://some-string-i-need-to-extract'.  Seems like I'd have to implement a "custom adapter" or something.  But I dont want to follow the 302 I just need to *save* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to use the requests library (which is almost part of the core libs at this point), you need to write a custom HTTPRedirectHandler using urllib2.

```
import urllib2

class CustomHTTPRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        ### DO YOUR STUFF HERE
        return urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)

    http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302

opener = urllib2.build_opener(CustomHTTPRedirectHandler)
post_data = {'foo': 'bar', 'some': 'otherdata'}
encoded = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_data).encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request('https://some-url', encoded)
opener.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: this seems like the most likely to work.  Just not sure now whether to go this route or try to use Requests, which seems much better documented.  Even so I guess we have to do some kind of "custom handler" because of the bogus URL scheme our corporate overlords are sending us.  Thanks all!

Comment: I've dealt with urllib and requests for many many years and I can say personally I would never think about using urllib for things that can be done via requests. Using solutions like the one I listed will end up creating a lot of tech debt even if they're integrated nicely. The equivalent in requests would just be `requests.get(... , allow_redirects=False)`